# Hiding the UINavigationController on the first .xib file only

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4.2

This may be a stupid question but I programmatically added a UINavigationController to my app.  If possible, I wanted to just add it to the top of all my windows except for the very first .xib.  Maybe even just hide it on my first .xib.  Is it possible to even do that?  I think of my first .xib file that opens up to the rest of my app like a cover page and I rather that blue bar not show up at the top of that.  I wish I could show you pictures but don't have enough reps yet. Thanks!

Below is the code I believe helps me to provide each page of app with the back bar:

```
#import "McCormick_TaylorViewController.h"

@implementation McCormick_TaylorAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    
  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]   
    autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[McCormick_TaylorViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"McCormick_TaylorViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  
    initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your McCormick_TaylorViewController's `viewWillApper:` method

just use bellow code...

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

and in other view controller in navigationbar ot display then in another viewController's viewWillAppear just use bellow code..

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Comment: I only have 1 view controller.  The rest are subclasses.  Is that ok? Should I add your second piece of code to the viewDidLoad in my .m files?

Comment: yes defiantly you can use if you want to hide navigationbar just one time when its load

Comment: but see ,for hide navigation bar use 1st code and for visible navigationbar use 2nd code... :)

Comment: Ok, it worked but the only thing is that it came back after I hit the back button on another page, lol.  Is there anyway to keep the first page from ever showing that blue bar?  Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: hey dude....for your this requirement i tell you use this code in you viewWillAppear Method then when your this firstview apper navigationbar hide.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
 self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]   
 autorelease];
 // Override point for customization after application launch.
 self.viewController = [[[McCormick_TaylorViewController alloc] 
 initWithNibName:@"McCormick_TaylorViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
  UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  
 initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
 [navController.navigationBar setHiden:YES]; // hides navigation bar
 self.window.rootViewController = navController;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: Using this methods takes away the entire navigation bar on the rest of the pages.  I have no way to get back.  Is there a way to only hide on the first page?

Comment: In Another View where you want navigation bar add this in ViewDidLoad: method [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];